# how to make auto pull down menu works with frameset?

Tags: javascript, menu, drop-down-menu, navigation, frameset

i failed many times. it's only works once. loaded once only. when i go to other option, it's not work. i copied the script from: http://javascript.internet.com/navigation/menu-auto-frames.html .  please trying the script, and check where's the missing script. tq.

Answer (score 0):

Please please please please DON'T use frames. You may think they're simple and solve all the world's problems. But in the meantime they're whispering behind your back, riffling through your wallet, taking your sister out on dates at dive bars with questionable clientel, and worst of all, will come back and infect you with the dreaded "bad site designitis" virus.

Comment: I understand but i like it coz it fast n easy to navigate.

Comment: The only time frames would be a timesaver is if your site is hosted on a server that does not have a dynamic script language (Perl, PHP, Ruby, etc..) enabled and also does not allow server-side-includes. At that point, you *MAY* be better off with having a sidebar navigation menu in a frame. But it is very very rarely the case that frames make life easier.

Comment: so what can i do? i really need it. it easy to navigate.